# Using yq to update a yaml file with artifacthub.io annotations

Tags: bash, sed, yaml, yq

I have a bash script which is updating a helm yaml file with [artifacthub.io annotations](https://artifacthub.io/docs/topics/annotations/helm/). However, my script is using variables that, I believe, requires the command to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Also, the `artifacthub.io` causes problems where artifact and io are separated. Which `yq` command can I use to update the `changes` and `images` annotation? I've also tried using `sed` to no avail.

```yaml
annotations:
  artifacthub.io/changes: |
    - Fixed linting issues.
  artifacthub.io/images: |
    - name: transmission
      image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/transmission:3.00-r0-ls75
```

I tried something like below but wasn't successful.

```sh
image=foo
yq e ".annotations."artifacthub.io/images"=\"${image}\"" -i "${chart_file_path}"
```

Comment: The fields `name` and `image` are not individual records but part of a multi-line string - "block" literal in YAML world. See - https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: You wouldn't be able to manipulate those fields directly, but form a multi line string with your required value. Run `yq e '.. style="double"' yaml` to see for yourselves

Answer (score 1):

To keep the yq query as readable as possible, I try to avoid escaping double quotes. By using single quotes around the yq query, double quotes do not have to be escaped. Additionally, single quotes can be close and reopen to concatenate bash variable to the query.

As for the keys with specials characters, you need to enclose them inside **double quotes** and **brackets** : `.annotations.["artifacthub.io/images"]`

Given the file:

```
# file.yml
annotations:
  artifacthub.io/changes: |
    - Fixed linting issues.
  artifacthub.io/images: |
    - name: transmission
      image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/transmission:3.00-r0-ls75
```

Executing this script:

```
image="foo"
yq eval '.annotations.["artifacthub.io/images"] = "'${image}'"' file.yml
#       |              |                     |    ||        |||
#       |              |                     |    ||        ||└> (a.1) close yq query
#       |              |                     |    ||        |└> (c) end string value
#       |              |                     |    ||        └> (a.2) open yq query (end concatenation)
#       |              |                     |    |└> (a.2) close yq query (start concatenation)
#       |              |                     |    └> (c) start string value
#       |              |                     └> (b) end key w/ special chars
#       |              └> (b) start key w/ special chars
#       └> (a.1) open yq query
```

Generates this outputs:

```
annotations:
  artifacthub.io/changes: |
    - Fixed linting issues.
  artifacthub.io/images: |-
    foo
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I'll test it out and see how it goes.